# ATM in Las Condes, Santiago Chile

Tags: internet, chile, atms, santiago-de-chile

Where can I find an ATM close to San Damian street, in Santiago, Chile?

Answer (score 3):

According to Google Maps there is a Banco Santander Santiago with an ATM on Avenida Las Condes about ¾ kilometre to the west:

[image: bank]